# How to avoid copy'n'paste in gradle?

Tags: spring-boot, gradle, build.gradle

I have a build.gradle file for my spring-boot application. I have a few environment details I wish to change for some of the gradle tasks. Specifically for the gradle tasks 'test', 'runSmokeTest' and 'bootRun'. In all the tasks I have to make the same calls, so I would prefer if I could extract a method out of that. Or a task. But whenever I do that, suddendly gradle no longer finds the functions that I require.

These are the calls I need to make:

```
systemProperties System.properties
systemProperty "spring.cloud.config.failFast", "false"
if (project.hasProperty("TEAM_ENCRYPT_KEY"))
    environment "ENCRYPT_KEY", "$TEAM_ENCRYPT_KEY"
```

The code works perfectly fine when included directly in the `bootRun` task, the `test` task and the `runSmokeTest` task via copy'n'paste. I would prefer not to duplicate the code. I tried the following approach to extract them from the bootRun task, but Gradle keeps complaining that he does not find the functions `systemProperty` and `environment`. Similarly if I use the Intellij integrated feature 'extract Method':

```
task specialConfiguration() {
    systemProperties System.properties
    systemProperty "spring.cloud.config.failFast", "false"
    if (project.hasProperty("TEAM_ENCRYPT_KEY"))
        environment "ENCRYPT_KEY", "$TEAM_ENCRYPT_KEY"
}

bootRun {
    dependsOn 'specialConfiguration'
}
```

How can I extract this short piece of code from the 3 tasks to avoid duplicate code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Gradle keeps complaining that he does not find the functions `systemProperty` and `environment`

This is a prime example where the [Kotlin DSL](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/kotlin_dsl.html) would shine. You would know exactly what methods/properties are available at any given time because it's a strongly type language unlike Groovy.

With that said, when you do the following:

```
task specialConfiguration() {
    systemProperties System.properties
    systemProperty "spring.cloud.config.failFast", "false"
    if (project.hasProperty("TEAM_ENCRYPT_KEY"))
        environment "ENCRYPT_KEY", "$TEAM_ENCRYPT_KEY"
}

bootRun {
    dependsOn 'specialConfiguration'
}
```

You are:

1. Declaring a task named `specialConfiguration`.
2. No type was specified so the type is [DefaultTask](https://docs.gradle.org/current/javadoc/org/gradle/api/DefaultTask.html).
3. Configure `bootRun` task to depend on `specialConfiguration`

I think you are assuming that `dependsOn` is like "configuring" a task when really it's just adding a dependency to the task. See [Adding dependencies to a task](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/more_about_tasks.html#sec:adding_dependencies_to_tasks).

I am assuming that `runSmokeTest` is of type [`Test`](https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.tasks.testing.Test.html). So tasks `test`, `runSmokeTest`, and `bootRun` all implement the [JavaForkOptions](https://docs.gradle.org/current/javadoc/org/gradle/process/JavaForkOptions.html) interface which is where the `systemProperties(..)`, `systemProperty(.., ..)` and `environment(.., ..)` methods come from.

With that said, since you know the three tasks you want to configure, and they all implement `JavaForkOptions` and in some fashion, you can do (Kotlin DSL):

```
import org.springframework.boot.gradle.tasks.run.BootRun


// Assuming this is a Test task type
tasks.register("runSmokeTest", Test::class)

// Define a new Action (configuration)
val taskConfig = Action<JavaForkOptions> {
    systemProperties(System.getProperties() as Map<String, Any>)
    systemProperty("spring.cloud.config.failFast", false)
    if (project.hasProperty("TEAM_ENCRYPT_KEY")) {
        environment("ENCRYPT_KEY", project.property("TEAM_ENCRYPT_KEY")!!)
    }
}

// Configure all three tasks
tasks.named("test", Test::class, taskConfig)
tasks.named("runSmokeTest", Test::class, taskConfig)
tasks.named("bootRun", BootRun::class, taskConfig)
```

Comment: I am totally with you on the Kotlin DSL idea and I am fighting that battle since a few months. I use it on private projects, but this is not a private project. I will figure out how to translate your solution to groovy and then test it.

Answer (score 1):

The Groovy version of Francisco Mateo's answer, in case anyone needs that.:

```
Closure<JavaForkOptions> configAction = {
systemProperties System.properties
    systemProperty "spring.cloud.config.failFast", "false"
    if (project.hasProperty("MOBTECH_ENCRYPT_KEY"))
        it.environment "ENCRYPT_KEY", "$MOBTECH_ENCRYPT_KEY"
}

# Configure the tasks with it
bootRun (configAction)
```